# How can I make Autocomplete or suggestions with JavaScript while user search for something?

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, search-suggestion

I made this in HTML and Java script And need to make a suggestions dropdown menu appears when the user writes first letter of the word he searches for

How can I make this?

```
   <html>
   <body>
   <input type="text" id="myInput" autofocus="true">
   <button id="btn" onclick="myfunction()">Search</button>
   <div id="outputArea" style="font-size: 30px"></div>
    <script>
     var acronyms = {
      omg: "Oh My God",
      lol: "Lough Out Loud",
      lmao: "Lough My Age Off",
      wtf: "What This Function"
      };
       var outputAreaRef = document.getElementById("outputArea");
         function myfunction(){
         var word = document.getElementById("myInput").value.toLowerCase().trim();
       if (acronyms[word] !== undefined) {word = acronyms[word];}
      outputAreaRef.innerHTML = word;}
      </script>
     </body>
      </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a HTML5 Element that makes this really easy. The `datalist` [tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp). You can hard code the items in the list or you can use some JS to populate the list.

You can see this answer for other options on the datalist.
[Html datalist values from array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17929356/html-datalist-values-from-array-in-javascript)

If you use JS to populate, here is what the markup ends up looking like:
`<datalist id="browsers">
      <option value="Internet Explorer">
      <option value="Firefox">
  <!-- more items here -->
  </datalist>`

```js
(function(browsers) {

  function addItems (list, container) {
      list.forEach(function(item){
      const option = document.createElement('option');

      option.setAttribute('value', item);
      container.appendChild(option);
    });
  }

  const browserList = ['Internet Explorer','Firefox','Chrome','Opera','Safari','Brave'];
  addItems(browserList, browsers);
}(document.getElementById('browsers')));
```

```html
<label for="autocomplete">Search for Browsers</label>
<input id="autocomplete" list="browsers">

<datalist id="browsers"></datalist>
```